# Memory Allocation, Bytes Exhausted PHP/LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, hosting, maatwebsite-excel

**Hey guys,**

I am developing a system using [Laravel Excel/Maatwebsite](https://laravel-excel.com/). What I'm trying to achieve is when a user inserts an excel file into the system, the system will check for a few things and then insert the data into the database.

**Here is an instance of the database schemas:**

```
Hadees:
h_id | h_english | r_id | h_last_raavi_id | b_id | s_id | k_id | h_status

Raavi:
r_id | r_english | r_status

Baab:
b_id | b_english | s_id | b_status

Section:
s_id | s_english | k_id | s_status

Kitaab:
k_id | k_english | k_status
```

**My controller:**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Section;
use App\Models\Raavi;
use App\Imports\HadeesImport;
use Excel;

class ImportHadeesController extends Controller{
    /**
     * Show the application import-hadees page.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(){
        $section = Section::where(['s_status' => 1])->get();

        return view('admin/import-hadees', compact('section'));
    }

    /**
     * This method uses the Excel facade to prep the excel file 
     * and extract data from it and uses App\Imports\HadeesImport 
     * class to insert each row in the database schema accordingly.
     * 
     * @param Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function importHadees(Request $request){
        $raavi = Raavi::where(['r_status' => 1])->get();

        if($request->file('hadees_sheet')) {
        } else {
           return response()->json(['status'=>'error', 'msg'=> 'No file present!']);
        }
    
        $temp = $request->file('hadees_sheet')->store('temp'); 
        $path=storage_path('app').'/'.$temp;

        $hadees = Excel::import(new HadeesImport($request->s_id, compact('raavi')), $path);

        if($hadees){
            return response()->json(['status'=>'success', 'msg'=> 'Successfully imported all the data from the file to the database!']);
        } else{
            return response()->json(['status'=>'error', 'msg'=> 'Unable to import data from the file to the database!']);
        }
    }
}
```

**HadeesImport Class:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use App\Models\Section;
use App\Models\Baab;
use App\Models\Hadees;
use App\Models\Raavi;

class HadeesImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow{
    /**
     * Global variable for section_id.
     */
    public $s_id;

    /**
     * Global variable for raavi's data.
     */
    public $raavi;

    /**
     * Construction function.
     * 
     * @param int $id
     */
    function __construct($id, $arr) {
        $this->s_id = $id;
        $this->raavi = $arr;
    }

    /**
    * This method is responsible for inserting the excel
    * sheet's rows data to the database schema.
    * 
    * @param Collection $row
    */
    public function collection(Collection $rows){
        $baab = Baab::where(['s_id' => $this->s_id])->get();
        $hissa = Section::where(['s_id' => $this->s_id])->first();
        $kitaab = $hissa->k_id;
        $first_raavi = 0;
        $last_raavi = 0;
        $baab_id = 0;
        $data = array();

        foreach ($rows as $row){
            if($row['hadees_arabic'] != "" && $row['hadees_urdu'] != ""){
                $baab_id = $this->baabCheck($baab, $row);
            
                foreach($this->raavi['raavi'] as $rav){
                    if(trim($rav->r_english) == trim($row['first_raavi_english'])){ 
                        $first_raavi = $rav->r_id; 
                    } else{
                        $first_raavi = 0;
                    }
    
                    $last_raavi = (trim($rav->r_english) == trim($row['last_raavi_english']))? $rav->r_id : 0;
                }

                if($first_raavi == 0){
                    $raavi = Raavi::create([
                        'r_arabic' => trim($row['first_raavi_urdu']),
                        'r_urdu' => trim($row['first_raavi_urdu']),
                        'r_english' => trim($row['first_raavi_english']),
                        'r_nickname' => trim($row['raavi_other_names']),
                        'r_status' => 1,
                    ]);

                    $first_raavi = $raavi->r_id;
                }

                if($last_raavi == 0){
                    $raavi = Raavi::create([
                        'r_arabic' => trim($row['last_raavi_urdu']),
                        'r_urdu' => trim($row['last_raavi_urdu']),
                        'r_english' => trim($row['last_raavi_english']),
                        'r_nickname' => 'n/a',
                        'r_status' => 1,
                    ]);

                    $last_raavi = $raavi->r_id;
                }

                $data = array([
                    'h_arabic' => trim($row['hadees_arabic']),
                    'h_urdu' => trim($row['hadees_urdu']),
                    'h_english' => trim($row['hadees_english']),
                    'h_roman_keywords' => trim($row['roman_keywords']),
                    'h_number' => trim($row['hadees_number']),
                    'r_id' => $first_raavi,
                    'h_last_raavi_id' => $last_raavi,
                    'b_id' => $baab_id,
                    's_id' => $this->s_id,
                    'k_id' => $kitaab,
                    'h_status' => 1
                ]);
            }
        }

        $hadees = Hadees::create($data);
    }

    /**
    * Checks if the baab exists in the database or not.
    * 
    * @param Collection $baab
    * @param Object $row
    * @return int - baad_id or 0
    */
    public function baabCheck($baab, $row){
        foreach($baab as $b){
            if(trim($b->b_arabic) == trim($row['baab_arabic']) || trim($b->b_urdu) == trim($row['baab_urdu']) || trim($b->b_english) == trim($row['baab_english'])){
                return $b->b_id;
            } else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It all was working fine when the data was less. Now I have *1400+* rows in **Raavi** table and *10,000+* rows in **Baab** table. Now whenever I try to import a sheet to the system it gives me this error:

> Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 37748736 bytes).

I think it's because of so long **foreach()** loop. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. If you guys have any suggestions about bad coding or bad logic building, please do let me know. I have been stuck on that issue for almost two days. Thanks in advance.

***P.s**: The error is same on the localhost and on hosting, just a difference in bytes. Which is due to different memory_limit setting, I believe.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All posted solutions mention raising the memory limit for PHP.

It does not work like that. You can't just throw more RAM at a problem. What if your server has 2GB of RAM and you upload a file that, with all the arrays created there, can use more than 2GB of RAM? What's next? Not to mention the risk of the server running out of memory and killing other processes. For example, if the server has shared PHP and MySQL running and PHP is causing the server to run out of memory, the OOM Killer will kick in and **might** kill the MySQL process.

The solution to your problem is to process that file in chunks. Laravel 6, for example, has a new type of collection, [Lazy Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#lazy-collections). They can help you speed things up. Your code might have to change in order to use chunk processing, but imho, that is the only way you can fix this problem.

I would also run this in a queue, not from a user request.

I also know that the package you are using supports both [chunking](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html) for reading and [batching](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/batch-inserts.html) for inserting.

Comment: I was thinking the same. As allowing more memory to a script is not a good solution. The thing is I don't know how to distribute file in chunks and then proceed the chunks for uploading into the database.

Comment: Then that is what you need to start reading about. One way would be for the import to just store those in a "temp" table, say imports_data. Then, have a queue job that reads from there in [chunks](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#chunking-results) or, like i said, lazy collections. Then, with a small number of rows read (100), you should be able to keep the memory usage lower.

Comment: Don't be afraid to submit new questions about new issues. You have a problem, and if you want to solve it the right way, you have to dig for the right answer. And most of the time, learn new things to solve your issue.

Comment: @Saud, also check the [package documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html) about chunking, might help you as well

Comment: Okay, Thank you for response. I'm gonna start reading and searching about chunks reading and writing. I have read about the *lazy collections*, looks like they can be a helpful feature. To use them I have to upgrade my project from 5.8 to 6.x. I'll start right away and post if anything happens. cheers!

Comment: Upgrade from 5.8 to 6.x is very easy. As I mentioned, do not be afraid to open up new questions once you do more research. 
If you think the answer was helpful, make sure to choose it as **accepted**, thank you!
I'm just so sick of seeing people telling others to just bump your memory, it'll all be fine.

Comment: Thanks man. I check the [package documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html) like you mentioned. It really helped me alot. And after a lot of reading and experimenting, I've achieved what I want to achieve. Looks like chunking is the correct solution to large data files. Cheers!

Comment: Glad you've chosen the right solution, and not blindly increased memory limit! Good job! Development is always about learning something new every day!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the memory_limit for certain files/pages/scripts to be more than what php.ini sets. Add a `__construct()` method and raise your memory limit:

```
public function __construct() {

     ini_set('memory_limit', '1G'); // change as needed, as long as your system can support it

     parent::__construct(); // If added in your controller. Probably not needed if you use it in your import class

}
```

Comment: Is it okay to do so, or safe? Please advice.

Comment: I do this all the time in some of my scripts, as they work with a lot of data. You just have to make sure that you have enough memory free on the system, and you don't raise the memory to more than what will be accessed. If you're going to have a lot of hits on the file, then raise it only as much as you need. It's better than raising the memory limit for the whole system, as it only raises the limit to what you need when you need it.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your responses. I have tried what you answered, now it's saying: `localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500`.

Comment: You'll need to check the server error logs for more information, since a 500 is a very generic error message.

Comment: I've checked the logs it says the same error: `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes)`

Comment: I would def not do this. Risky, dangerous, 1 request can make the server run out of memory. Poor solution. A better way would be to find a way to process that doc in chunks, in the queue. And when I say chunks, I mean chunks to read and insert into all your tables

Comment: @aynber I have raised the `memory_limit=2048M` in **php.ini** file and `ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');` in my **HadeesImport** class. But, it's still saying the same. I think 1G `memory_limit` to a script is enough. What do you suggest?

Comment: don't do that! Read my response. Raising the memory limit **is not safe** and it's not a fix to your problem, merely just a patch

Answer (score 1):

Extend your `memory_limit`. For 'localhost', in `php.ini`-

```
memory_limit=2048M
```

And restart your server.

Comment: Data not inserting in your database is another issue. Let me check your code.

Comment: I have already done that. Sometimes it stops showing error whenever I raise the limit in php.ini file but the system won't insert rows in the database and shows success message. Sometimes it just say http server error:500

Comment: I would def not do this. Risky, dangerous, 1 request can make the server run out of memory. Poor solution. A better way would be to find a way to process that doc in chunks, in the queue. And when I say chunks, I mean chunks to read and insert into all your tables

Answer (score 1):

Set the memory_limit to be unlimited for a specific file to override php.ini `memory_limit`

```
// put it in your construct 

ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
```

Comment: Would it be okay do so? I don't think setting memory_limit to unlimited would be a great idea. Because it makes sure that a poorly written script don't get all the memory.

Comment: I would def not do this. Risky, dangerous, 1 request can make the server run out of memory. Poor solution.  A better way would be to find a way to process that doc in chunks, in the queue. And when I say chunks, I mean chunks to read and insert into all your tables

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same issue while running

```
Model::insert();
```

I have solved it by disabling the query log and unsettling all the events for the query.

```
DB::connection('your-connection')->disableQueryLog();
DB::connection('your-connection')->unsetEventDispatcher();
```

But beware it should only use while importing data.
Otherwise, your other package's events and logging system will not work for your queries run after these two lines.

Comment: If you encountered the same error(*out of memory*) while using `Model::insert();`, you can try the `array_chunk()` method. But you have to limit your chunks size to MySQL's `max_allowed_packet`.